# React native AR (Pokemon GO)

Tags: react-native, camera, pokemon-go

i lately started an AR App using React Native. In that app, i have to catch items with my phone camera. The problem is that i can't see how to know if a GPS point (longitude,latitude of the item) is in the camera's field of view or not. Is there any framework or a mathematic formula to have this result.

Comment: want to create an application where the user opens his camera and if the camera captures a GPS point a message is displayed and if it turns the message disappears like https://static1.squarespace.com/static/5627eb27e4b00e3c672920f6/t/59bb120e03596eb13780c9b0/1505761132430/ar_image.png?format=1000w

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For GPS datas from pictures, camera recording, can be taken from metadata using  lib **Exif** https://github.com/headmax/exif-js https://www.scantips.com/lights/exif.html

Comment: sorry but I want to create an application where the user opens his camera and if the camera captures a GPS point a message is displayed and if it turns the message disappears like https://static1.squarespace.com/static/5627eb27e4b00e3c672920f6/t/59bb120e03596eb13780c9b0/1505761132430/ar_image.png?format=1000w

Comment: lol you think this is simple like to watch video :). On this way you need camera gps localized, locate at runtime exif data to extract the geolocalization long lat but how do you take data (position) to known the position where are the 3D object on map screener?

Comment: yes yes I understand I first started by opening the camera and I have the position of the terminal and I have the position of the places to display from the server my problem is how to know that a GPS point (already known) is in the field of view of the camera

Comment: Abdelkadre El Maghri look my example based on a picture  to test you make a screenshot form you camera and then upload the file to the app and if there is a GPS metadata it will give you the position on google map where the picture was taken from .. https://codepen.io/headmax/pen/eGPxYo

Comment: to known after driving GPS data by Exif you can create canvas from you site to activate the camera and show the map around people if 3D object a hidden somewhere.

Comment: if you need help i can give you but need to send you my mail post me message in private way. or come to the chat

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157142/discussion-between-abdelkadre-el-maghri-and-headmax).